# How to prevent unbalanced partitions when reading data from hive using spark SQL?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

we are processing data stored in a hive table using spark SQL (v2.1.0). we find that our spark tasks exhibit a heavy skew. e.g.: in below `p_75` of the tasks had an input size of 127.1MB but the max input size was 634.7MB:

[image]

How can we get a more even distribution of the input size over the tasks?

we tried changing the # of partitions while reading data but it does not fix the skew:

[image]

Below are some other helpful properties of our hive table:

```
| ROW FORMAT SERDE                                                                |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'                 |
| STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                                                           |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'               |
| OUTPUTFORMAT                                                                    |
|   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
```

The HDFS files themselves are stored in parquet format with snappy compression (files end in `.snappy.parquet`) which is splittable per [this](http://boristyukin.com/is-snappy-compressed-parquet-file-splittable/) link